# Unable to run R script containing gWidgets2 in command prompt

Tags: r, gwidgets, rscript

Say I have a basic r script:

```
require(gWidgets2RGtk2)
w<-gbasicdialog("Stage 1.5")
visible(w)
```

I save it, and attempt to run it with command prompt using a batch file that looks like this:

```
@echo
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\test\test.r"
PAUSE
```

When I attempt to run this script, I get this error after all the packages are loaded:

```
Error in UseMethod(".gbasicdialog") :
  no applicable method for '.gbasicdialog'applied to an object of class "NULL"
Calls: gbasicdialog -> .gbasicdialog
Execution halted
```

Can anyone see if I am doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the script to this:

```
options(guiToolkit="RGtk2")
library(gWidgets2)
w <- gbasicdialog("Stage 1.5")
visible(w)
```

Also I assume you meant `@echo off` as the first line in the batch file.  The `PAUSE` statement could be omitted.